# Copy data between 2 separate database servers (VB.net)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I just upgraded my SQL Server from a SQL Server Express to a full version. I'm now trying to import my old data to the new SQL Server.

My current solution is to loop through each row in the first database and insert them individually on the new server. I've tried restoring my old server on the new, but there are a lot of limitation on the express version I used to have, which won't allow me to export/import data.

I've worked with bulk insert a bit, but I can't seem to figure out a good solution to bulk insert from one server to the other.

Hope you can help me :) I'm working in vb.net

Comment: I would not use vb for this. Possible solutions 1) SSIS 2) Linked server 3) BULK INSERT

Comment: Why don't you just do a **backup** on your SQL Server Express instance, copy the resulting `.bak` file to your "full" SQL Server, and restore the database there? That seems like the simplest, fastest, most convenient way to do this....

Comment: I believe we have tried this backup and restore on new sql server approach, but as i remember we had a conversion problem with the old server log file and the new server, since it required the old log file or something like that. I'll give it a try later today and report back.

Comment: You should be able to do a backup restore (as marc_s says) or alternatively a  detach/attach.

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty simple once I figured out how to do it. I used the detach/attach function within Microsoft SQL. First I connected to the old server and detached the entire database I wanted to move to the new server. Then i copied the database file and log file to the new server and re attached the database to the new server. Pretty simple only took a few minutes :) Thanks to everyone who wrote an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to forget VB and do this inside the databases.

Perhaps the simplest way is to link the databases together (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)).  You may need to do this from the full version to the express.  Then you can copy tables using `select into` or `insert`.

Alternatively, you could export the data into files and load the files into the newer version.

If you have complex data structures, you probably want to script out the database so you can re-create it exactly as is.  If you don't have that much data, you can even script it out with the data.  The scripting option is available in SQL Server Management Studio.

So, you have many options without bringing the data into VB, one row at a time, and storing it back out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the article and give it a try. Is it okay if I contact you if i need further assistance? :)